# Stop YouTube Video from Playing when FlexSlider Slide is out of view

Tags: javascript, youtube, flexslider

I am trying to put some YouTube embedded videos into a FlexSlider Carousel / Slider. The issue I am having is to have the video stop if the slide is not in view. Currently, if you play the video and select a new video, the previous one keeps playing.

Expected: On slide change, stop the video.
Actual: On slide change, the video keeps playing.

HTML:

```
<section class="videolist">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
          <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xcJtL7QggTI" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </li>
        <li><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/a3ICNMQW7Ok" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </li>
        <li> <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S-thTTqefls" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe> </li>
        <li> <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bey4XXJAqS8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe> </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li> <img src="https://quidsup.net/wallpaper/abstract/the-cube-1920x1080-wallpaper-5189.jpg" alt="This is the alt text of the video"> </li>
        <li> <img src="https://www.setaswall.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Spaceship-Background-20-1920x1080.jpg" alt="This is the alt text of the video"> </li>
        <li> <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/trlzN6b.jpg" alt="This is the alt text of the video"> </li>
        <li> <img src="https://i.redd.it/vjcavsc1lcs11.jpg" alt="This is the alt text of the video"> </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {  
  $('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
  }); 
  $('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: "#carousel"
  });
});
```

I have a codepen up here [YouTube FlexSlider Carousel | Codepen](https://codepen.io/f1ss1on/pen/JxQwYr)

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help, it was figured out by adding in some js.

```
$(window).load(function() {  
  $('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    asNavFor: '#slider',
    start: function() {
      $('#carousel li').on('click', function(e){
        stopVideos();
      });
      $('#carousel li').on('click', function(e){
        stopVideos();
      });
    }
  }); 
  $('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: "#carousel",
    start: function() {
      $('.flex-next').on('click', function(e){
        stopVideos();
      });
      $('.flex-prev').on('click', function(e){
        stopVideos();
      });
    }
  });
});

function stopVideos() {
  $('.iframe-vid').each(function() {
  this.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*')
  });
}
```

Comment: what is `.iframe-vid`,? a div element around your iframe element? the iframe element itself? if so, why didn't you use `$('.flex-slide-item iframe')`?  Also where can wer learn more about  `postMessage()`